# Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-2.0

I have a problem with Django. Actually I want to create a login panel in my new site but when I try to write address the debugger respond me a error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/account/login
Using the URLconf defined in firmowa.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^account/
The current path, account/login, didn't match any of these.
```

My firmowa.urls is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
    ]
```

And the project urls.py is:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
]
```

I'm looking a solution from few hours but still nothing.

Comment: append the slash at the end of your request : /account/login/

Comment: If u r using `path` feature in Django 2.0 u don't need to supply `r'^account/',` just `path('account/', include('account.urls')),` is enough. same for login url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`path` is a new feature in Django 2.0 and works different than the old `url`. Don't use regex in `path`. If you need regex, use `re_path` instead, but in your case there's no need for that.

Change your code to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
]
```

etc. and it should work.

More on the topic [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url( r'^$', views.index , name='index') ,
]
```